# How do i simplify this menu

Tags: go

So I'm starting a project that I've wanted to do for a while and the first thing I have to do is print a menu
I was wondering whether there was a nicer / better way of coding this code.
To "prettify" it I'd call it
I was thinking of doing something like

```golang
fmt.Println("You have chosen option " + input)
```

But I have to call a different named function for each option chosen, so I'm not sure how I'd make this work

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello welcome")
    var input int
    fmt.Println("Please choose an option:")
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
    if input == 1 {
        fmt.Println("Option 1 chosen")
    } else if input == 2 {
        fmt.Println("Option 2 chosen")
    } else if input == 3 {
        fmt.Println("Option 3 chosen")
    } else if input == 4 {
        fmt.Println("Option 4 chosen")
    } else if input == 5 {
        fmt.Println("Option 5 chosen")
    } else if input == 6 {
        fmt.Println("Option 6 chosen")
    } else if input == 7 {
        fmt.Println("Option 7 chosen")
    } else if input == 8 {
        fmt.Println("Option 8 chosen")
    } else if input == 9 {
        fmt.Println("Option 9 chosen")
    } else if input == 10 {
        fmt.Println("Option 10 chosen")
    } else {
        fmt.Print("Not an option")
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `switch` statement

Comment: cheers i'll look into this, i totally forgot this was a thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest making a map of options number to functions, like this:

```
func func1() {
    fmt.Print("Option 1 Chosen")
}

func func2() {
    fmt.Print("Option 2 Chosen")
}

func main() {
    funcs := map[int]func() {
        1: func1,
        2: func2,
    }
    fmt.Println("Hello welcome")
    var input int
    fmt.Println("Please choose an option:")
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
    f, ok := funcs[input]
    if !ok {
        fmt.Print("Not an option")
    } else {
        f()
    }
}
```